# Android emulator not starting up

Tags: android

Starting an avd from the AVD Manager (Nexus5 API22 on OSX Yosemite 10.10.5)

**Error trace:**

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   /tmp/darwin-x86_64-clang-3.5/lib/libc++.1.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1/tools/emulator   Reason: image
>   not found

Comment: Looks like something is using homebrew. If it is not you it is a bug in a different manager

Comment: @Mark a different avd manager ? Is there one for ios ?

Comment: sorry typo/spell checker I meant AVD Manager

Answer (score 3):

This solution helped me, https://stackoverflow.com/a/49511666/641611

Modify the PATH was enough,

```
export ANDROID_SDK=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK/emulator:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$PATH
```